# Java TreeMap<String, String> returns null even if the key exists

Tags: java

I have a class which extends TreeMap with one external method.
The external method "open" suppose to read lines from a given file in the following format "word:meaning" and add it to the TreeMap - put("word", "meaning").

So I read the file with RandomAccessFile and put the keys-values in the TreeMap and when I print the TreeMap I can see the proper keys and values, for example:

```
{AAAA=BBBB, CAB=yahoo!}
```

But for some reason when I do get("AAAA") I get null.

Any reason why it's happening and how to solve it?

Here is the code

```
public class InMemoryDictionary extends TreeMap<String, String> implements
    PersistentDictionary {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; // (because we're extending
                                                    // a serializable class)
private File dictFile;

public InMemoryDictionary(File dictFile) {
    super();
    this.dictFile = dictFile;
}

@Override
public void open() throws IOException {     
    clear();
    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(dictFile, "rw");
    file.seek(0);
    String line;
    while (null != (line = file.readLine())) {
        int firstColon = line.indexOf(":");
        put(line.substring(0, firstColon - 1),
                line.substring(firstColon + 1, line.length() - 1));
    }       
    file.close();
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {    
    dictFile.delete();
    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(dictFile, "rw");       
    file.seek(0);
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : entrySet()) {            
        file.writeChars(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue() + "\n");
    }
    file.close();
}
```

}

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Don't include sigs. in questions, they are noise.  This question has some very strange characters in the text of the key/value.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete example which illustrates your problem.

Comment: {�A�A�A�A=�B�B�B�B, �C�A�B=�y�a�h�o�o�!}..What is this??

Comment: ignore the questions mark, refresh the page...

Comment: My best guess is that you're not implementing the `Comparator` the `Comparable` interface or the `equals` method correctly, which leads to this incorrect behaviour... But without code, we can't know.

Comment: @RaduMurzea: That shouldn't be the case with `String`

Comment: @jlordo Whoops, didn't see it was `String`s we're dealing with...

Comment: @gilsilas: Can you also post the code, where you print `{AAAA=BBBB, CAB=yahoo!}` and after that receive `null` for `.get("AAAA");` ?

Comment: In your open method, make sure there is anything put into the map, and provide evidence for it.

Comment: @jlordo at the end of the open method I did: System.out.println(this) and this.get("AAAA");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the "question marks" from a previous version of your question *are important*.  they indicate that the strings you thought you were seeing are not in fact the strings you are using.  RandomAccessFile is a poor choice to read a text file.  You are presumably reading a text file with a text encoding which is *not* single byte (utf-16 perhaps)?  the resulting strings are mis-encoded since RandomAccessFile does an "ascii" character conversion.  this is causing your `get()` call to fail.

first, figure out the character encoding of your file and open it with the appropriately configured InputStreamReader.

second, extending TreeMap is a very poor design.  Use aggregation here, not extension.